# Visual Studio 2013 debugger showing weird values for std::string

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I have a large cmake generated solution with many projects in it. For some reason I cannot view the contents of a string because according to the debugger `_Bx._Buf` contains some garbage.

`text.c_str()` returns correctly `"Hello"`.

The problem does not only occur for local strings. Functions that return `std::string` also appear to be garbage in debugger whereas in reality they are OK.

For clarity: the screenshot was made *after* the assignment line was executed. So it is not that text is uninitialized.

Another info: If I create a new console project in visual studio then it works fine I can see the contents of any string. It is only this cmake generated project I have issues with.

The Character Set of the project properties is set to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set"

Debugger Type is set to "Auto" but I have tried "Mixed" and "native Only" too but it is all the same. I can't see strings.

Does anyone have a clue what setting causes this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Could not reproduce with Visual Studio 2015. Does it work with a simple "Hello World" project built from scratch? Did you debug a release build?

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations turned on?  If so what it looks like is the compiler never even initialized the string.

Comment: Post code that includes a [mcve]. Very unlikely that the debugger is horribly broken and you are the first to have noticed.

Comment: Capacity of 335038624 is somewhat suspicious, is it not?

Comment: It does work with a simple Hello World app. It is a x64 Debug build. Optimizations are turned off.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Yes the capacity also looks bad.

Comment: @F.E.Land Cannot reproduce with Visual Studio 2013 (x64 Debug build). Please provide more information on your project configuration.

Comment: 1. Try reproducing this with a small cmake-generated solution. 2. Extract actual cl and ld invocations from build logs and scan them for suspicious flags.

Comment: Make sure your breakpoint is *after* the string declaration.

Comment: Looks like a known issue: [Debugger not displaying std::string values](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/966912/debugger-not-displaying-std-string-values)  There's a note saying that they planned to fix in an upcoming update to VS 2013, but not sure if that actually happened or not.  Worth checking to make sure you have all of your VS updates?

Comment: @PhilBrubaker The issue you linked is about visualizer not working with the /clr flag. My code is native c++ and the natvis files are working I checked that. The problem lies deeper because the input of the natvis files are already corrupted.

Comment: @n.m. This is a good suggestion. I would do this if I had the time. Thanks.

Comment: @F.E. Land, if you view it in the debug watch window, how about the result? Sorry for that I also couldn't repro it in my side, if possible, please use the latest VS like VS2015 or VS2017, debug it again. Or you could share the sample for us to repro this issue.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT It looks the same in the watchwindow. A workaround I have found is to do this in QuickWatch: text.c_str(). Unfortunately I cannot post more of the project because it is huge.

Comment: @F.E. Land, I post an answer, is it helpful for you? Would you please share us the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that the version of STL that you are using (in his CMake project) doesn’t match the STL.Natvis they have. On my VS 2013 (Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\stl.natvis), basic_string has two natvis entries:

```
<Type Name="std::basic_string&lt;char,*&gt;">
    <DisplayString Condition="_Myres &lt; _BUF_SIZE">{_Bx._Buf,s}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="_Myres &gt;= _BUF_SIZE">{_Bx._Ptr,s}</DisplayString>
    <StringView Condition="_Myres &lt; _BUF_SIZE">_Bx._Buf,s</StringView>
    <StringView Condition="_Myres &gt;= _BUF_SIZE">_Bx._Ptr,s</StringView>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[size]">_Mysize</Item>
        <Item Name="[capacity]">_Myres</Item>
        <ArrayItems>
            <Size>_Mysize</Size>
            <ValuePointer Condition="_Myres &lt; _BUF_SIZE">_Bx._Buf</ValuePointer>
            <ValuePointer Condition="_Myres &gt;= _BUF_SIZE">_Bx._Ptr</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>
```

And

```
<Type Name="std::basic_string&lt;unsigned short,*&gt;">
    <AlternativeType Name="std::basic_string&lt;wchar_t,*&gt;" />
    <DisplayString Condition="_Myres &lt; _BUF_SIZE">{_Bx._Buf,su}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString Condition="_Myres &gt;= _BUF_SIZE">{_Bx._Ptr,su}</DisplayString>
    <StringView Condition="_Myres &lt; _BUF_SIZE">_Bx._Buf,su</StringView>
    <StringView Condition="_Myres &gt;= _BUF_SIZE">_Bx._Ptr,su</StringView>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[size]">_Mysize</Item>
        <Item Name="[capacity]">_Myres</Item>
        <ArrayItems>
            <Size>_Mysize</Size>
            <ValuePointer Condition="_Myres &lt; _BUF_SIZE">_Bx._Buf</ValuePointer>
            <ValuePointer Condition="_Myres &gt;= _BUF_SIZE">_Bx._Ptr</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>
```

Since you could get the same value during entering the STL display string into the watch window, you may need a different STL.natvis for your std::string for it to work. You should try stepping into text.c_str() to see what it is actually returning. I feel that it’s a newer STL.

Comment: Using a newer version of stl.natvis does not solve my problem. What do you mean by checking what c_str returns? I have debugged into c_str in which leads into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstring  The code in it:  `const value_type *_Myptr() const
  { // determine current pointer to buffer for nonmutable string
  return (this->_BUF_SIZE <= this->_Myres
   ? _STD addressof(*this->_Bx._Ptr)
   : this->_Bx._Buf);
  }`

Comment: @F.E. Land, just to make this issue clearly, do you mean that you got this issue in watch window, Enter the following into the watch window:

Text.c_str().
Text._Myptr()
Text._Myres
Text._Bx
_BUF_SIZE, how about the result? As far as I know, the natvis is just evaluating expressions, you can evaluate all of those same expressions by hand.

Comment: text.c_str() 0x000000000022aac8 "Hello" const char *  
text._Myptr() 0x000000000022aac8 "Hello" const char *  
text._Myres 8790823929686 unsigned __int64  
text._BUF_SIZE _BUF_SIZE (16)  
std::_String_val<std::_String_base_types<char, std::allocator<char> >::_Val_types>::__Ut1

Comment: This is a very common occurrence since at least VS2012, and is still present in VS2017. It happens in debug as well as release builds.