# Visual Studio debugger doesn't display std::string properly in debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2019, stdstring

Me and my team are having an issue with Visual Studio displaying gibberish instead of proper string contents when I pause my program. The string inside has correct data, it's just that the debugger of VS gets lost somehow.

I marked the correct contents in green, incorrect in red.

[image: std::string gibberish issue in VS 16.3.4]

You can see that the `std::string` defined as

```cpp
const std::string testStdString = "contents of std::string";
```

Displays as `"\bÄĎD\x19"` in debug hover and watch window. But the C-string from `.c_str()` displays fine. Console written to with `cout` also displays fine.
This broken value changes on each run.

In raw view mode, you can see that the pointer contents, when displayed as ASCII, look like what the debugger thinks are the string contents. So maybe some short string optimization related issue?

[image: raw view of the string]

If you decode that as a string:

```
"\bÄĎD\x19"
    [0x00000000]: 0x08 '\b'
    [0x00000001]: 0xc4 'Ä'
    [0x00000002]: 0xcf 'Ď'
    [0x00000003]: 0x44 'D'
    [0x00000004]: 0x19 '\x19'
    [0x00000005]: 0x00 '\0'
```

It matches the `buf` property visible in the raw view: `0x0000001944cfc408` (reverse order).

Issue only affects `std::string`, `std::wstring` and C-strings work fine. When I try to use `std::string::c_str()` it works fine too.

When I try with a simple new project, this issue doesn't occur - but on our 18 solution with native C++ and C# UWP solution it does.

We don't use any non-Microsoft compiler nor standard library. We use the VC142 compiler with `/permissive-` (conformance mode) all on the most up to date Visual Studio 2019 (16.3.4). Tried with VS141, doesn't help.

This started to happen after some update and was not fixed at least until VS 16.3.4. The previous version it worked on for sure was VS 2017, but some of my team say perhaps the early 2019 versions worked for them too.

Possibly related (but unanswered and about VS 2013): [Visual Studio 2013 debugger showing weird values for std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868715/visual-studio-2013-debugger-showing-weird-values-for-stdstring)

I reported the issue in [the Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/782573/visual-studio-debugger-doesnt-display-stdstring-pr.html), maybe they'll know something.

Update 2019-10-22:

Tried to create a minimal project by copying project and removing libraries, referenced projects and shared projects but keeping the configuration of the main project and solution - can't replicate the issue this way. So it's not (just) the configuration, it's something about the linked projects and libraries. The projects/libs are either built by VS, or are from Windows SDK or Intel Media SDK.
Will try to remove them one by one later on, maybe this will help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Please keep the code and debugger text as text rather than an image.

Comment: @chris you understand that watch window is important on this image and not the code?

Comment: @chris, why should I? This question is about a tool not displaying properly. Image form is exactly what is needed here.

Comment: Regarding *unclear what you're asking* close vote - I want Visual Studio to properly display `std::string` contents.

Comment: You could check, if you have enabled the option "View as HEX" in the context menu when debugging the variables

Comment: @Logman, The code is important as context for the watch window. Meanwhile, the watch window works just as well as text. Keep in mind screen readers won't let their users know what's in that screenshot. In addition, the image host may be blocked.

Comment: @chris, this is a good reason. Adding text of important parts.

Comment: FWIW, I would definitely say that the later-added raw view works much better as an image. My original comment was for the watch window specifically, which can be summarized as a list of name-value pairs given an indication that this list corresponds to the watch window. One other benefit that I didn't mention is that it allows copying the incorrect text to play around with it. This can be especially handy for encoding issues, for example.

Comment: @Simon, checking or unchecking the *View as HEX* doesn't change anything

Comment: Since it affects `std::string` but `std::wstring` displays properly, I would expect it has something to do with wide character or narrow character display of the `std::string` contents. In other words VS Debugger is displaying `std::string` variables as narrow character rather than wide character.

Comment: @RichardChambers: thought so too at first, but look at the hex dump of the displayed string - that are not the same contents but with different encoding. Also on each run it's randomly different (adding that last bit of info into the question).

Comment: Take a look at a similar forum posting https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2bdadc84-66f3-4852-a2b4-f59862a434ea/the-debugger-isnt-displaying-stdwstring-values?forum=vcgeneral of someone with the opposite problem, `std::string` is fine but `std::wstring` is not. There is mention of the `autoexp.dat` file which controls how debugger data is displayed.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883238/tutorial-manual-how-to-create-visualizer-in-autoexp-dat

Comment: Hi, what's the result if you delete the .vs folder in solution directory? And since this issue only occurs in your current solution, I think you can check the project properties between current project and new project, maybe something in project properties causes this issue :)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT: Removing the .vs folder (and recreating it on another machine) doesn't help. About differences between solutions, see update on question - the same configuration (but without related projects) stops having this issue

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for your trouble-shooting? Since this issue is non-reproducible, it's hard for us to check it for you:( If you have any progress when removing them one by one, feel free to share the useful info here :)

Comment: Hi, @LanceLi-MSFT, I haven't been able to put more hours into this issue yet, sorry. This still is an active (and annoying) problem. If I would be able to remove project by project from the solution, it might help to point at least at the combination of projects that are the problem - but they're all tied in together and removing each one requires a lot of work. I cannot publish the sources of the whole project, and can't get a minimum reproduction demo. Maybe there's some other way I can send you the required information to debug this? Some kind of a dump of the debugger or similar?

Comment: Got response from product team, they(the C++ team) believe this is due to `mixing libs compiled against multiple versions of the CRT`, already created a bug for this issue, but they are still waiting on a repro to dig further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

​Someone on my team found a potential fix, we did have different CRTs. One of the libraries was `/MD` while the others were `/MDd`. But changing that, did not fix much. 
We used `/MD`, because under `/MDd` the library was malfunctioning. The library in question was the Intel Media SDK's mfx_dispatch project.

What fixed this was changing the toolset of that library from 141 to 142. On the latter, the `std::string` was readable in the watch window.

Still having different problems with debugger, but this was the worst one.